bulk_update cloudflare KV attribute error python
I am using python to bulk_update the KV using this
https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/python/resources/kv/subresources/namespaces/methods/bulk_update/
when using an identical code as the example i get an error
    response = client.kv.namespaces.bulk_update(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NamespacesResource' object has no attribute 'bulk_update'

my versions are:
python 3.12.6

cloudflare == 3.1.1
pydantic == 2.9.*
httpx == 0.27.*

any idea how to fix this? the API toekn are working when using D1 db so it is not a token

It turns out that the documentation is not correct it is
bulk.update

NOT
bulk_update

